# Exibição modal com lista do banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, eu tenho um banco de dados que esta sendo exibido em uma lista no meu site mas quero colocar um botão para abrir um modal e exibir as informações de cada linha do db porém sempre que abro o modal ele só exibe a ultima linha dos registros.

O codigo usado

```
while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_produtos)) {
            # code...
                echo "<section>"
             . "<span>Tema : " . $row_produto['tema'] . "</span><br>"
             . "<span>ID : " . $row_produto['id_nec'] . "</span>"
             . "<div class='div_pai-btn'>"
             . "<input class='btn_edit-prod btn_prod' type='button' value='Editar Produto'>"
             . "<input class='btn_add-prod btn_prod' type='button' value='Adicionar Imagem'>"
             . "<input class='btn_exc-prod btn_prod' type='button' value='Excluir Produto'>"
             . "</div>"
             . "<div class = 'cont_img-prod'>"
             . " <img src = 'upload/" .$row_produto['id_nec'] . "/" .$row_produto['imagem'] ."'>"
             . " </div>"
             . " </section>"
             . " <hr>"
             .  "<div class='edit_modal'>
                     <span>Tema : " . $row_produto['tema'] . "</span>
                </div>";
        };
```

agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Comment: Já passou pela sua cabeça que o recomendável seria a utilização do ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar javascript e ajax, passa o id do array que vc quer buscar no onclick do modal, faz uma requisição via ajax e mostra os dados no modal. O modal também precisa de um id.